# Append in a text file in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a txt file from C# as follows:

```
 File.WriteAllText("important.txt", Convert.ToString(c));
 File.WriteAllLines("important.txt", (from r in rec
                     select r.name + "   " + r.num1 + "   " + r.num2 + "   " + r.mult + "   " + r.rel).ToArray());
```

But the second File.WriteAllLines overrides the first entry in the file. Any suggestion how can I append data?

Answer (score 7):

You should use `File.AppendAllLines`, so something like:

```
File.WriteAllText("important.txt", Convert.ToString(c));
File.AppendAllLines("important.txt", (from r in rec
                     select r.name + "   " + r.num1 + "   " + r.num2 + "   " + r.mult + "   " + r.rel).ToArray());
```

System.IO.File.AppendAllLines exists from .NET framework 4.0. If you are using .NET framework 3.5, there is AppenAllText method, and you can write your code like this:

```
File.WriteAllText("important.txt", Convert.ToString(c));
File.AppendAllText("important.txt", string.Join(Environment.NewLine, (from r in rec
                         select r.name + "   " + r.num1 + "   " + r.num2 + "   " + r.mult + "   " + r.rel).ToArray()));
```

Comment: I got error systemIO . file does not contain definition for AppendAllLines.

Comment: Method System.IO.File.AppendAllLines exists for sure. Please check if you miss spelled it.

Comment: AppendAllLines is from .NET 4.0. See my updated answer if you are using some older version of .NET framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 File.WriteAllLines("important.txt",  Convert.ToString(c) + (from r in rec
                     select r.name + "   " + r.num1 + "   " + r.num2 + "   " + r.mult + "   " + r.rel).ToArray());
```