# C# programming writing to a file user data

Tags: c#, file, streamwriter, saving-data

I am trying to develop a user interface, where users can input their name, id and hometown and I am saving it into a text file.

```
File.WriteAllText(path,"name"+" " + textBox2.Text+ Environment.NewLine + 
"number"+" "+ textBox3.Text+Environment.NewLine + "town"+" " + 
textBox4.Text+Environment.NewLine );
```

This works but the data of the users is written in the text boxes and it works only for the first user, when I enter new data and click the button with the function, it overwrites the first user's data and that way I am not able to save more than 1 user's data.

Please suggest the required modification in the code.

Comment: Please see the help section on how to ask a question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: possible duplicate of [Append in a text file in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960064/append-in-a-text-file-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`File.WriteAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext(v=vs.110).aspx) will always overwrite the current file if it exists. Use [`File.AppendAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendalltext(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
string name = textbox1.Text;
string number = textbox2.Text;
string town = textbox3.Text;

File.AppendAllText(path, String.Format("name{0} \n number{1} \n town{2}", name, number, town);
```

`File.AppendAllText` will append the data, whereas `File.WriteAllText` will overwrite any existing data.

Answer (score -1):

you can also use StreamWritter with append mode setted to true
you can see http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamwriter and https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/36b035cb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx 
for more informations

Comment: post the links in comments