# I need to save multiple items in a List<> in a .txt file, how can I do that? I don't have any code to show atm :')

Tags: c#, list, listbox, save

```
    private void btnOpslaan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
    }
```

Comment: `File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\myFile.txt", myList);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Append in a text file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960064/append-in-a-text-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You should specify what is `T` in your `List<T>`. If `T` is string, no problem, just pass the collection. If it's not a simple string, you may want to serialize it instead.

Answer (score 0):

First add System.IO namespace to the code.

```
using System.IO;
```

Then use this line:

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\YourFileName.txt", yourList);
```

> Creates a new file, writes a collection of strings to the file, and then closes the file.

Be careful, If the target file already exists, it will overwritten.
If you want to append lines, try '[File.AppendAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalllines?view=net-5.0)' method.

More about [File.WriteAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=net-5.0)